# How to fix `TypeError: argument of type 'ArcGIS' is not iterable` error on geopy?

Tags: python, geopy

I wanted to make a program where you enter your address(the example in the code is a Dutch address) and then the program gives as output the longitude and the latitude od that address. I also tried to make it more user-friendly so if the entered address doesn't exist, the program will say that.
the code is:

```
from geopy.geocoders import ArcGIS
nom = ArcGIS()
adres = input("enter your adress as folows:\n 32 Gunterstein, Amsterdam, 1081 CJ\n vul in: ")

n = nom.geocode(adres)
if adres in nom:
    print("longitude:",n.longitude)
    print("latitude:", n.latitude)
else:
    print("adress doesn't exist, please try again.")
print("end")
```

if the user enters a valid address the code works but when I try that out by entering nonsense I get the following error:

```
enter your adress as folows:
 32 Gunterstein, Amsterdam, 1081 CJ
 vul in: nonsense
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "breede_en_lengte_graden.py", line 7, in <module>
    if adres in nom:
TypeError: argument of type 'ArcGIS' is not iterable
```

What is wrong with the code that I get that error?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try using `try` and `except` instead of `if else`?

Comment: What should `if adres in nom` do in your understanding?

Comment: @FlyingTeller what I think that if  does is that it checks if the address is valid, but when I look at the answers to my question it isn't like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it throws an error on erroneous address.

```
n = nom.geocode('sdf324uio')
n is None
```

> True

Just check if `n` is `None` to see if a valid address was passed to it.

Edit:

It's funny that actually `nonsense` exists as place and it returns a valid location (it was my first attempt for a non-existing address):

```
n = nom.geocode('nonsense')
n
```

> Location(Nonsense, (-23.56400999999994, -46.66579999999993, 0.0))

Comment: Thx for the explanation now I understand

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it with a `try-except` block:

```
try:
    print("longitude:", n.longitude)
    print("latitude:", n.latitude)
except AttributeError:
    print("adress doesn't exist, please try again.")
print("end")
```

You can also do it with an `if-else` block, but you'll have to do it little bit differently:

```
if n is not None:
    print("longitude:", n.longitude)
    print("latitude:", n.latitude)
else:
    print("adress doesn't exist, please try again.")
print("end")
```

The reason for this kind of checking is that the `nom.geocode(adres)` doesn't fail on invalid addresses, instead it simply returns `None` and that is assigned to be the value of `n`.

Comment: Thx that helped a lot